# AngularJS 2 seed + System.JS - New .ts file doesn't compile

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

I pulled the latest angularjs2 seed application from github (https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed) and got it running in webstorm.

Now I wanted to add a simple `load.ts` file which preloads some components:

```
declare var System: any;
declare var esriSystem: any;

esriSystem.register([
    'esri/geometry/Point',
    'esri/geometry/geometryEngineAsync',      
    'esri/Map'
], function() {
    // bootstrap the app
    System.import('../app')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
}, {
    outModuleName: 'esri-mods'
});
```

I would like to use this module inside a new `map.service.ts`: `import { Map } from 'esri-mods';` it tells me that it `cannot resolve file 'esri-mods'`

The overall structure looks like this:
[image]

And the `system.config.js` as follows:

```
System.config({
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  map: {
    app: 'src',
    typescript: 'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
    angular2: 'node_modules/angular2',
    rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs'
  },
  packages: {
    app: {
      defaultExtension: 'ts',
      main: 'app.ts'
    },
    angular2: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

What is missing for the module to be usable within the application?

Comment: Do you have a type definition file for 'esri-mods'? Typescript doesn't actually run your module loading JS or anything else in your application, it just relies on interfaces and classes present in .ts and .d.ts files that are part of the compilation context.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that actually. I have to check that

Comment: If you *don't* have a type definition file, and don't have the time right now to deal with this, you can just do `import 'esri-mods'` at the top, and declare that some `Map` class exists: `declare let Map: any`. This will get rid of any compilation errors.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have now installed the type definitions `typings install --global github:Esri/jsapi-resources/4.x/typescript/arcgis-js-api.d.ts` but it is still telling me the same error. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: It doesn't look like `esri-mods` is part of the definition file (see for yourself [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/arcgis-js-api/arcgis-js-api.d.ts)). Are you sure the module you're supposed to import isn't just `'esri'`?

Comment: have you checked `Enable Typescript Compiler` and `Use tsconfig.json` in  `setting > Languages & Framework >typescript `  ??